# How do I get Backbone.js AutoComplPop in Vim?

Tags: vim, backbone.js

How do I get Vim and AutoComplPop to work with Backbone.js syntax?

AutoComplPop works properly for HTML, CSS, PHP, and JavaScript.  It pops up automatically when in Insert mode and can be popped up manually as well.  How do I get Backbone.js syntax to do the same?

I've tried without success:

- [mklabs vim-backbone plugin](https://github.com/mklabs/vim-backbone) -> auto/manual complete didn't work but syntax highlighting did
- [wei ko kao's/othree's javascript-libraries-syntax](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4428) -> auto/manual complete doesn't activate
- [igetgames' vim-backbone-jscomplete](https://github.com/igetgames/vim-backbone-jscomplete/blob/master/autoload/js/backbone.vim) -> auto/manual complete doesn't activate

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, do any of the completions work with manual triggering? I don't know those plugins, but they presumably use *omni-completion*, triggered in insert mode via `<C-X><C-O>`.

If you have that one working, the next step is to enable that in AutoComplPop. I have never tried this, but you may have to configure something in there (`g:acp_behaviorUserDefinedMeets`?). You can check AutoComplPop's help and its implementation of the built-in support for Perl, XML, CSS, etc.

Comment: Yes, Ingo, several other languages' completions work with both manual triggering and auto completion.  Yes, I believe they are using the omni completion feature of Vim.  I don't know why when adding the Backbone vim files Vim didn't use them for auto completion.  I will look into the docs for acp_behaviorUserDefinedMeets for clues.  Thanks.